# How to optimize a SQL Query which gets stuck on "Creating Sort Index"

Tags: mysql

I am executing the following SQL Query on a remote client, and it is taking quite a long time to execute (5 minutes and longer).

From [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/90061/mysql-profile-on-query-creating-sort-index-using-75-of-the-total-time), one of the answers suggested that *'Creating sort index' is the database figuring out the order of your returned values based on your 'order by' clause.'*

Is there a way to optimize this query?

```
SELECT column1 FROM my_database where '2017-01-19 09:00:00' > time_stamp and '2017-01-19 05:00:00' < time_stamp order by time_stamp desc limit 5000;
```

Comment: Do you have any index's at all? If not I'd create one on the `time_stamp` field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your query:

```
SELECT column1
FROM my_database 
WHERE '2017-01-19 09:00:00' > time_stamp and
      '2017-01-19 05:00:00' < time_stamp
ORDER BY time_stamp desc
LIMIT 5000;
```

The best index for this query is a composite index on `my_database(time_stamp, column1)`.  Unfortunately, MySQL does not really recognize the `desc` for an index, so you probably cannot avoid the sort.

Comment: It can, and has always been able to, scan an index backward.  `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT...` may give a suitable clue.